# How to integrate Percy storybook testing in a gitlab ci pipeline?

Tags: javascript, angular, gitlab-ci, storybook, percy

I would like to add a job to my current Gitlab CI pipeline in order to test my storybook. The aim is to check if there are differences between the two releases and make the pipeline fail if there are some. The problem is that I do not find much information in [Percy's documentation](https://docs.percy.io/docs/gitlab-ci). If someone knows how to get feedback from Percy and where I can find documentation about it would be very nice.

I tried successfully to trigger a Percy build locally, which worked also in my CI but my CI does not care at all about the build result.